# Angular Multiple Observable Requests with using Service

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v59qus) In my application I am using service to communicate between

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { TransferModel } from '../models/transfer';

@Injectable()
export class TransferService{
    constructor(){}
    private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject(new TransferModel());
    getData = this.paramSource.asObservable();
    setData(param:TransferModel) { this.paramSource.next(param)} 
}
```

My problem is that when I go to components, it works well but in pages send other pages request also. I mean for example I am in Courses.component

```
 constructor(private transferService:TransferService,private dataService:DataService,sessionService:SessionService,private router:Router) { 
    this.transferService.getData.subscribe(x=>{
      this.transfer=x; if(!this.transfer.ExamId || this.transfer.ExamId<=0){ this.router.navigateByUrl("/home");return;}
      this.dataService.Post(URLS.url.coursePage.getCourses,{Id:this.transfer.ExamId}).subscribe(elem=>{
        this.courses=elem;
      });
    });  
 }
```

code above gets courses list when I click one course , below function run and

```
 goToSubject(id){
    this.transfer.CourseId=id;
    this.transferService.setData(this.transfer);
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/subjects");
  }
```

goes to subjects component. In subjects component I send request with constructor.

```
 constructor(private transferService:TransferService,private dataService:DataService,sessionService:SessionService,private router:Router) { 
     this.transferService.getData.subscribe(x=>{
       this.transfer=x; if(!this.transfer.ExamId || this.transfer.ExamId<=0){ this.router.navigateByUrl("/home"); }
       this.dataService.Post(URLS.url.subjectPage.getSubjects,{ExamId:this.transfer.ExamId,CourseId:this.transfer.CourseId}).subscribe(elem=>{
         this.subjects=elem;
       });
     });  
   }
```

but here also another page's request call too such as in image.
I need that every page send only one its request.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Please check if one of the request's method is OPTIONS instead of GET or POST. If so it's a CORS [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) request.

Comment: Problem is not options. My problem pages which is using service send all pages requests but I want every page send its own request @MichaelD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume since `transferService.getData()` returns a `Subject`, which you are subscribing, and probably not unsubscribing <s>on component `onDestroy`</s> anywhere, those subscription remains alive and are invoked.

Your `goToSubject()` calls the `this.transferService.setData(this.transfer);` which basically invokes all the subscriptions.

<s>You would need to hold on the `Subscription` being returned when you `subscribe` and call `unsubscribe()` on `ngOnDestroy()`</s>

```
subscription: Subscription;
constructor(...){
    this.subscription = this.transferService.getData.subscribe(x=>{
        ...
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.subscription) {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.subscription = null;
    }
}
```

if you have multiple `subscribe()` on your component, maybe you would like to leverage some sort of self-subscribing-implementation like [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil)

Note: Angular HttpClient subscriptions are self-unsubscribing by default, so you don't need to call `unsubscribe()` when you call `httpClient.get().subscribe()`. For everything else, you would need to call `unsubscribe()`.

**UPDATE:**

After looking at the stackblitz demo you've provided, it was confirmed that the issue was with the `transferService.getData()` subject. However even with the `ngOnDestroy()` unsubscribing it was still calling because you had `this.transferService.setData(..)` before you redirected which basically invokes the `transferService.getData().subscribe(...)`.

To fix that without major refactoring you would have to make it 'Subscribe only once' or 'automatically unsubscribe as soon as it subscribe is called'. Which brings us back to `takeUntil`.

in both courses.component & subjects.component

```
constructor() {
    const subj: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
    this.transferService.getData
        .pipe(takeUntil(subj))
        .subscribe((result) => {
            subj.next(true);
        });
 }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

[Stackblitz demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5uhwj)

Comment: I put into all related components but still send multi requests @j4rey

Comment: I added demo in question you can check it there

Comment: again same problem can u create demo for this please ?